# Looking for a device to detect the amount of smoke

Tags: sensor, smoke-sensor

I'm building a cold smoker monitoring system. With cold smoking you need to maintain consistent levels of smoke and not necessarily a consistent temperature like with hot smoking. I'm trying to find a sensor to use in the PID loop. Does anyone know a smoke sensor that gives a level of particulate smoke and not just present/absent? Even a course level should be sufficient to detect when levels are low and either more wood is needed or more heat. Preferably something with I2C or a linear/semi-linear analog reading.

Comment: Shopping questions aren't a great fit here because parts always change and availability is dependent on market/region; have you considered existing approaches such as measuring scattering/turbidity of the air to evaluate them first, before settling into either a) searching for a commercial sensor with that mechanism or b) implementing it yourself?

Comment: I think you mean "coarse level", not "course level".

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of sensors aimed at air quality monitoring, such as Sharp's      GP2Y1010AU0F with an analogue output depending on the smoke density, or fancier units such as the Sensiron's SPS30 that has internal algorithms to give counts for different particle sizes.

The problem you have with both of these is that they are intended for air quality monitoring, and might saturate with the levels of smoke in a smoker. You may also experience issues with wood resin settling on the optical components and causing long-term drift or failure.

You may have better results with a discrete solution with a phototransistor and LED - although you will still have the settling problem, you can tune this to your smoke density level much more easily.

A further option is to sense the smoke levels capacitively, although I'm not aware of any commercial modules to do this. A quick search turned up a patent (WO2014022525A2) for using this as a smoke alarm, but you may still run into the issues with drift, both from the change in air density and plate spacing as you apply heat and from deposition of material on the capacitor plates.

Comment: If you went with an optical sensing method like laser/led and phototransistor, note you could build a motorized cover to expose the lenses only during periodic sampling to decrease how often you have to clean the lenses.  An even better solution would be to use an air curtain to protect the lenses, but the disadvantage is it would agitate the air in the box and suck some smoke out so it would be more viable with a larger smoker.